# Will access specifiers still be intact when code is converted from high level to low level language?

Tags: c++, assembly

It's like will all the private ,protected data members that are present in high level languages still be like that or will they all be public when changed to assembly from a higher level language?

Comment: Low level languages does not have these constructs.

Comment: There will be no *members* to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No. Mostly No.

Private and protected members is really a compile time thing. It guides the compiler into helping you not to make silly mistakes in the code. And the compiler does that by refusing to produce assembly code that violates the restrictions.

So in the resulting executable there is no code that would violate the rules, because such code would never be successfully compiled. In that sense, the restrictions are still there.

But on the assembly or hardware level there is nothing like private or protected. It is just bytes. If you were to write code directly in assembly, you could read all the private C++ variables, and nothing would stop you.

Answer (score 1):

C++ access specfiers are restrictions on how you name things in the C++ language.  They have no impact on the runtime behaviour of the abstract machine C++ is specified in terms of (other than, say, permitting strange memory layouts).  The low level implementations in turn basically emulate said abstract machine.

So no.

Comment: Did you change the nickname? :) While your answer is correct, somehow I have a feeling OP will have troubles understanding it.